# I can't find the build folder of my project in Android studio

Tags: java, android

I looked for the build folder under the app folder but couldn't find it.
Anyone got any idea how can I show/find it?
Thanks!
(I'm new to android programming)
[image: build folder screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried to build your project yet?

Comment: Build Folder is not shown in Android Studio. If you want to see build folder. Then go to location using Window Explorer.

Comment: @Oozeerally Found it. 
I needed to build the project first!
Thank for your time!

Comment: @Anas I will add my comment as an answer, please accept it so others that face your issue can find the solution

Comment: @Oozeerally done, ty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to see the `build` directory you will first need to build your project, this will then produce the `build` directory.